# match array against database

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array(61) which contain possible user names and i want to validate each one of them against database entry. i am using the following code:

```
foreach(profileName("Dev","Db") as $k => $val){
    $db->query("SELECT profile_name FROM eb_user_account WHERE profile_name = '$val'");
    if($db->numRows() == 0){
        echo $val ." [match found at key: {$k}]";
        break;
    }
}
```

`profileName("Dev","Db")` function holds the array. this code works nice and smooth and break exactly where match doesn't occur. i am just curious if there is a faster and better way to perform this task. please suggest me.

with thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a combination of mySQL's `IN` operator, and the PHP[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
$query = sprintf(
    'SELECT profile_name FROM eb_user_account WHERE profile_name IN (%s)',
    implode(',', profileName("Dev","Db"))
);
```

It's worth noting that if you're using parameterized queries it is not possible to pass an list of arguments of arbitrary length. eg:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (?)');
$rs = $stmt->execute(array(implode(',', $myarray)));
```

Will fail. The number of parameters in the `IN` statement must match the number of placeholders. eg:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (?,?,?)');
$rs = $stmt->execute(array(1,2,3));
```

On second thought...

```
$myarray = profileName("Dev","Db");
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($myarray), '?');
$query = sprintf(
    'SELECT profile_name FROM eb_user_account WHERE profile_name IN (%s)',
    implode(',', $placeholders);
);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$rs = $stmt->execute($myarray);
```

Should have everything parameterized correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's `IN()` clause, e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE profile_name IN ('foo', 'bar')
```